# How to add columns to a flat file

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package where I take CSV files and load them into a DB. I then have a task with a SQL statement to get the data I need and export into a CSV file. I need to add columns to the CSV file that are not present in the db table. How I can add these?

Comment: It depends, what data you want to put there: Either create a database view to include the additional columns and query this view instead of your table or use the "Derived Column" functiod to create additional columns directly in your Data Flow.

Comment: what will be source of extra columns for CSV output

Answer (score 0):

In the flat file connection manager, go to advanced tab and add columns to your csv file. And you can add derived columns to fill them, or you can add values to your select statement